# How can I get the thumbnail of a QuickLook Preview Item?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm previewing various documents using QLPreviewController. The controller has a "list view" option where it displays the image and title of all of the documents in the controller.

[image: Standard QLPreview List View]

How can I get that image so I can display it on a different screen?

I'm trying to make a "view file" screen where it shows all of the file details and a thumbnail preview. Then clicking the thumbnail would bring the user to the full preview.

[image: File Detail Page]

Comment: No API for this on iOS.

Comment: That's a bummer.. Is there any way to view apple's source code? Something like iCloud drive seems to be able to generate thumbnail views to display. Or is this done server side or something like that?

Comment: There is API for documents in iCloud Drive only. `NSURLThumbnailsDictionaryKey`.

Comment: @sargturner did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @zaitsman I did not! We ended up using simple icons for the file thumbnails. I don't believe Apple would supply an API for this but if you have control over your file list endpoint you could have it return a link for the thumbnails (which should be very small) in the response. Then you could get the images you need to display and cache them on the device.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, there isn't API for having the thumbnail of a file (like `AppCoda-Image` or `AppCoda-PDF`) but you can get an icon like `AppCoda-Pages`, `AppCoda-Word`, `AppCoda-Keynote` or `AppCoda-Text.`

```
// Create an `UIDocumentInteractionController` with the file URL.
let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: <#URL#>)

// Get icon
_ = controller.icons[0]
```

This will return the icon but not the thumbnail.